# An Equation Involving the Trigamma Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, special-functions

Let $N$ be a positive integer, and consider the equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \psi^{(1)} \left( \frac{x+1-n}{2} \right) = \frac{N}{x},
\end{equation}
in the real unkown $x > N - 1$, where $\psi^{(1)}(x)$ is the [trigamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function).

I have conjectured that this equation has no solution. Does someone have an idea of a possible proof?

Any help is welcome.

NB From the [series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function) of the trigamma function we know that the map $(0,\infty) \ni x \mapsto \psi^{(1)}(x)$ is strictly decreasing. So our statement is proved if we can prove the inequality
\begin{equation}
\psi^{(1)}(x) > \frac{1}{x} \quad (x > 0),
\end{equation}
but I do not know how to prove it for now.

Comment: The last inequality is just
$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac 1 {(k + x)^2} > \int_0^\infty \frac {dk} {(k + x)^2}.$$

Comment: @Maxim Wonderful one-life proof!!!! Thank you very very very ... much, Maxim for your help. I would never be able to find it by myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our system has actually no solution as conjectured, since the inequality stated in the note above holds true. More precisely, one can prove that

\begin{equation}
\psi^{(1)}(x) > \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2x^2} \quad (x > 0).
\end{equation}
For a proof, see e.g. Elbert and Laforgia [On Some Properties of the Gamma Function](https://www.jstor.org/stable/119868?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Section 2; Gordon, [A Stochastic Approach to the Gamma Function](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975134?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Theorem 4; Alzer, [On Some Inequalities for the Gamma Function](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1997-66-217/S0025-5718-97-00807-7/S0025-5718-97-00807-7.pdf), Theorem 9.